# A novel about a group of scientists who think they've invented a teleporter

Tags: story-identification, novel, parallel-universe, teleportation

I read this a few years ago, around 2015/16 I think and I cannot for the life of me remember the title of it and googling isn't helping at all.

It was about a group of scientists who are working on creating a teleporter. It seemingly works (if I remember correctly, it connects to another room somewhere else in the facility), but it turns out that it's actually a gateway to alternate universes, so every time someone or something passes through it they're either slightly different, or very different. Things get real when an invisible field leaks out of it that affects everything it touches, and horrors start to spill out.

There is a moment where one of the scientists is doing the standard daily test of the machine and returns a mangled mess. The main character has a habit of flipping a coin, which leads to them discovering the invisible field when it's noticed that the coin has been subtly changing while in the air. Nearing the climax of the plot, there is a sizable alien force that starts to attack from the field. That's about everything of significance I can think of.

If anyone can help with the title, I'd really appreciate it. I don't think it was a particularly successful or big novel but I'd like to revisit it or the author's other works.

Comment: "The Infinitive of Go" by Brunner maybe?

Comment: Can you remember any other details about the story or the appearance of the cover? Did you read it as part of a collection, or a standalone novel/novella? The more information you can provide about the story (and when/where you read it), the more likely it is that someone can identify it for you. We recommend that you look at our Guide: [How to Ask a Good Story-ID Question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see what info you can add to this question.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - While my initial inclination also said _The Infinitive of Go_, on a thorough reading of the question, I don't think it's that one; there wasn't any field leaking out of the 'poster' and no real horror aspect to the story.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I agree, it's why I posted a comment instead of an answer. It depends how confident the poster is in the horror aspect

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez Hi there, thank you for answering! Unfortunately that isn't it. I think I downplayed the horror aspect of it. there is a moment of body horror and near the end there is a sizeable conflict with a kind of alien force if I recall correctly.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin It was a standalone, and honestly it was more of a novella in hindsight. I can't remember anything about the cover which is frustrating. Other things that made it standout was there is a moment one of the scientists does the standard daily test of the machine and returns a mangled mess. I also remember the main character has a habit of flipping a coin, which leads to them discovering the invisible field when it's noticed that the coin has been subtlely changing while in the air.

Comment: @ArrBee That's good information! It would be good if you could edit it into your question so that it is more visible

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez very true, added to my question. I've still been attempting to google up some info and i'm driving myself insane lol starting to wonder if I ended up in a alternate universe where this book doesn't exist.

Comment: And just like that, I found it myself. It's "The Fold" by Peter Clines. Scanning through lists of goodreads was the key lol thanks for the replies Clara and Jeff!

Comment: Write that up as an answer, so it can collect votes, and after 24 hours you can accept your own answer (a time-honored Stack Exchange tradition, when you find your own answer or solution).  Make sure it's a *good* answer -- include details about what makes this the right choice for the story you were looking for.

Comment: Please do not edit your answer into your question. Answers belong in answers. I have reverted your edit.

Comment: It's not what  ou're looking for, but SCP-970 is like this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[*The Fold*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23164927-the-fold) by Peter Clines (2015)

The second in The [Threshold Universe](https://www.goodreads.com/series/249747-threshold) series. It's the story of Mike Erikson, a man gifted with an eidetic memory, who is recruited to join a team of scientists who have invented a device that is capable of shrinking the distance traveled of anyone who uses it by hundreds of feet with a single step. The machine makes use of computer equation and magnetic fields to "fold" dimensions, which leads to much more dangerous outcomes than the promised reality of teleportation.

[image]

Comment: *blink* I hadn't realized there were more books in the series. Nice to know.

Comment: Me neither.   Liked this one a lot

Comment: There is also a short story by Stephen King about a similiar premise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mrs._Todd%27s_Shortcut

Comment: I'm just listening to this as an audiobook. I did "14" over the past few days. I like it a lot. I guess I got lucky by simply being online at a time when your question was high in the recent activity list.